# XAML INotifyPropertyChanged to Update UI

Tags: c#, xaml, interface, inotifypropertychanged, propertychanged

I am new to XAML and trying to find a better way to do it.
I noticed that UI is not updated right away when there is change in code behind.

I want to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, so GUI is notified about the change and updates.

Initially in XAML, I've set visibility set to hidden(for TextBlock or image) or true (isCheck or isEnabled).

During the program in the code behind, I set to visible or false.

But GUI does not get updated. Below is the framework what I have for the page. 
All of the properties change (changed to visible) when the button is clicked.

The only difference is that I have multiple pages, and you can move from one page to another with the button. After the user clicks the button, it goes to next page and updates the UI.

Right now I am using the `UpdateGUI()` after I make a change to update the UI.
UpdateGUI();

```
public void UpdateUI()
{
    //remove this function from the code below.
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(delegate { }));
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
    <Grid Margin=" 0, 20, 0, 0">
        <StackPanel Margin="20, 0, 0, 0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Image x:Name="CheckBox1Img" Margin="0, 2, 0, 0" Source="{StaticResource doneCheckImage}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                <CheckBox x:Name="Checkbox1" Content="CheckBox1"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image x:Name="CheckBox2Img" Margin="0, 2, 0, 0" Source="{StaticResource doneCheckImage}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                <CheckBox x:Name="Checkbox2" Content="CheckBox 2"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image x:Name="CheckBox3Img" Margin="0, 2, 0, 0" Source="{StaticResource doneCheckImage}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox3"  Content="CheckBox 3"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <Button x:Name="Button1"  Click="Button1_Click" Height="20"  Content="Click" Width="50"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button2"  Click="Button2_Click" Height="20"  Content="Button to disable" Width="200"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Checkbox1.IsEnabled = false;
            Checkbox2.IsEnabled = false;
            Checkbox3.IsEnabled = false;
            CheckBox1Img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            CheckBox2Img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            CheckBox3Img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            Button2.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

App.XAML

```
<Application.Resources>
    <!-- Blue Check Image -->
    <BitmapImage x:Key="doneCheckImage" UriSource="blueCheck.png" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Did you look into MVVM pattern? How you are calling UpdateUI function?

Comment: Setting the properties of the controls from code behind should fine, the controls should update immediately.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a Viewmodel (Simple .cs class) in a new ViewModels folder
2. Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interace like this:

   ```
    public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged{
    //Example for a valid INotifyPropertyChanged member
    private bool _visibility;

    public bool Visibility
   {
       get { return _visibility; }
       set { _visibility = value;  OnPropertyChanged("Visibility");}
   }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName){
               if (PropertyChanged != null)
               {
                   PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
               }
           }
   }
   ```

Now Create a new .cs class - call it something like BooleanToVisibilityConverter.cs:

The code should look something like this:

```
 public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if((bool)value == true)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now go to your xaml where you want to bind to this viewmodel there add this after `<page` tag - Intellisense will help you if you just type in ViewModel:

```
xmlns:vm ="using:APPLICATIONNAME.ViewModels"
```

Further add to your xaml:

```
  <Page.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModel x:Key="MyVM"></vm:ViewModel>
</Page.Resources>
```

Now Build your project and then select in the xaml the ui element where you want to bind your data.
Then open the property window for the ui element and search for Visibility; click at the square and press create dataBinding, select Static Resource and Set the Value Converter to the BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

[image]

You can access your viewmodel in c# by setting the datacontext in xaml. You may want to take a deep look in mvvm theory first.